# dmesg + how to exclude warning messages from dmesg in order to see the completely kernel messages

Tags: centos, rhel, kernel, dmesg

on our rhel 7.2 server  we can see that all lines from `dmesg` are looks like this

```
uname -r
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64



[26202771.781769] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26202771.781782] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26202771.781800] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26202831.650423] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26202831.650431] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26202831.650441] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26202891.499068] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26202891.499075] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26202891.499085] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26202951.362930] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26202951.362944] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26202951.362967] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26203011.251183] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26203011.251197] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26203011.251216] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26203071.081705] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26203071.081718] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26203071.081735] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26203130.936870] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26203130.936886] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26203130.936912] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26203190.801805] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26203190.801811] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26203190.801820] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[26203250.658782] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[26203250.658795] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff88ccf723b280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[26203250.658813] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
```

in spite the above lines are not indicate on major problem!

**BUT** the real problem is that we not see the other important kernel messages that should be figured

how to exclude the Error messages about - `Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires`

Comment: filtering through `grep -v "Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires"` is no option, I gather?

Comment: but all lines from dmesg are like the errors no additional lines

Comment: The kernel does not lose messages. So, there's no other messages in the kernel log buffer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller that's not true at all, the ring buffer does have a maximum size and on a system that's spamming messages (in this case from acpi, on one of my systems from a wlan card) you'll easy lose the beginning. 256KB is a common cap

Comment: Hm, @Fox, that's pretty much exactly what I meant with "there's no other messages in the kernel log buffer"?

Comment: the kernel _does_ lose messages. in the order they were received once it reaches the size cap. and in some cases the refill is very fast

Comment: ah, yes, you're right, I meant "lose" as "sporadically forget"; you're right, in effect "pushes them out of the ring buffer" is a loss of message.

Comment: Maybe run a supported kernel and it won’t generate the errors?  That is a very old kernel running on a very old release of RHEL7.

Comment: kernel upgrade is major process , and these are production machines , so it difficult to ask customer for this scenario

Comment: we also checked rhel machines with 7.6 version and dmesg looks exactly as on rhel 7.2 ( old kernel versio )n

Comment: so this kernel mass isn't because old kernel or little new kernel version