# how to exclude not important kernel messages that hide the real kernel messages lines

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

we have HP HW ( DL 380 G10 ) physical REDHAT machines. ( version 7.5 )
and as we can see the kernel messages are filled by the following messages about.

```
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
```

the problem is that all these messages are actually hide the important kernel messages.

example

```
[23040.319045] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23040.319052] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[23100.182918] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[23100.182926] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23100.182935] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[23160.038404] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[23160.038411] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23160.038421] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[23219.897894] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[23219.897905] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23219.897924] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[23279.741745] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[23279.741760] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23279.741778] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
[23339.617647] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20130517/exfield-389)
[23339.617655] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PMI0._PMM] (Node ffff9209cebcf280), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20130517/psparse-536)
[23339.617665] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20130517/power_meter-339)
```

any advice how to ignore this messages?

Comment: how do they hide the kernel messages?

Comment: all lines from kernel are like this

Comment: are you saying that some lines are missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dmesg + how to exclude warning messages from dmesg in order to see the completely kernel messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684092/dmesg-how-to-exclude-warning-messages-from-dmesg-in-order-to-see-the-completel)

Comment: Of course it doesn't answer your question, but it's clearly a duplicate.

Comment: You should not be looking directly at the kernel log device, but configure rsyslogd to filter the messages as desired, then direct the result to the console or a log file that you can tail.

Comment: about rsyslogd to filter , you can give an answer , from redhat we can see this post - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41278